# As a U.S. citizen, how does income tax work for income from non U.S. companies?

Tags: united-states, taxes, income-tax, irs, foreign-income

I've done freelance work online previously mainly for U.S. companies, and the tax forms were either 1099-MISC or 1099-NEC. 2020 was my first time doing freelance work online for foreign companies. Coincidently it seems like it was also their first time hiring US citizens to do work for them because when I ask them for the tax forms, they seem unsure about it. Can someone let me know what's the right tax forms I should be expecting from them?

Comment: What is the other country [this matters  because tax treaties between countries are not all the same]? Did they send you a tax slip for that country?

Comment: Also - were you always present in the US when you were doing the work?

Comment: @Grade'Eh'Bacon I was always present in the U.S. and the non U.S. company is an entity in Hong Kong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably won’t be getting any tax forms from them, but it doesn’t matter. Your business needs to declare all of its revenue, whether you get a 1099 or not.

Add in whatever they paid you in 2020 to the other freelance revenue you had when you do your taxes.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how to declare the income myself? What tax form do I need to fill in?

Comment: @user3667089 I’m confused. You said you’ve done freelance work in the past and received 1099 income. How did you do your taxes? Generally, business income goes on Schedule C. Line 1 is where you enter the total amount of business revenue that you had. This will include any amount you received that was reported on a 1099, but also includes any business income you received that was not reported on a 1099.

Comment: I usually consolidate all the 1099 forms and send it to a CPA and let him do the rest. Based on what you said, I guess on top of my 1099 forms, I can simply notify the CPA about this additional income, and he should be able to fill out Schedule C. Line 1 correctly based on this information, right?

Comment: @user3667089 Yes. Tell your CPA what you took in that’s not on a 1099, and he’ll take care of it.